# Strapi Docker on DigitalOcean - Content types and admin user is disappearing after a while

Tags: docker, filesystems, digital-ocean, strapi

I hope one of you can help me with an answer to this problem I have. I am currently deploying a website to DigitalOcean using Docker and I have decided to use Strapi for content creation. Creating and setting up everything works fine, but after a while when I go to log in on the strapi admin panel all the files are gone and I have to create an admin user once again.

I read something about DigitalOcean not allowing changes in the file system and that might be why everything is deleted when they update or restart. But how do I get around that so that I can use Strapi Docker on my droplet? Is there a fix out there I don’t know about?

Frontend is a Node Express container, my database is a mongodb container and then I am running Nginx as reverse proxy and then for the backend I am using Strapi Docker as CMS for content creation.

Answer (score 0):

Reason why everything gets wiped is because you are working in a development database.

You will have to create new database(production ready - managed database) and connect it to your strapi(you can add it as a component to your App & add db details to env variables).

After that in order to make images work, you will need to create Spaces to save your uploaded images via one of the following plugins(they all do pretty much the same):

- https://github.com/lbadger/strapi-upload-digitalocean
- https://github.com/AdamZikmund/strapi-provider-upload-digitalocean
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-provider-upload-do
  I personally use last one as it had simplest docs but I imagine it wouldn't be hard to get around other two options as well :)